# Mouse wheel Chrome bug

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, scrolling, mouse-wheel

When I use the mouse wheel in Chrome (15.0.865.0) to scroll in most text area boxes (even in the questions with similar titles area in SU as I am writing this), I can scroll far beyond the text, and the scrollbars keep shrinking.

Is this normal behavior? How can I fix this?

Comment: No, that's not normal. (I'm sure I've seen it before, but it was once in a while.) <br /> Does it happen in other browser? What version of Chrome are you using? Does it happen in all pages? Can you try a different mouse?

Comment: It cannot be the mouse, edited post to contain chrome version, does not happen in IE 9.

Comment: I have not seen this myself.  Have you noticed that Chrome makes text input boxes resizable?  There is a gadget in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Don't think this is the same thing, and I don't know what gadget you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you experience strange behaviour such as this try going through a few steps to exclude other factors. Try them in the order of least difficulty.

- Check your add-on/extensions in Chrome go to chrome://extensions/ disable/remove anything to do with scrolling/auto page loading such as eg '[AutoPatchWork](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd)'
- Try to remove other extensions that do any page specific manipulation
- There are sometimes cross-tab issues check if you have other plug-ins active in other tabs that could be a problem, flash/silverlight/pdf/etc
- Specific mouse software that has scrolling control features.
- Update to a beta version of Chrome, or downgrade to a stable version.
- Close all tabs and re-start the browser.
- Reboot your machine (*just for completeness of the list*).

Comment: None of these solved the issue.

Comment: @soandos Try creating a new windows profile, and installing chrome under that user as a different test case to see if it's also an issue in a slightly cleaner environment?

Comment: No change. Not sure why that would ever make a difference.